# How to disable Jquery function when window width smaller than X

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie, and I couldn't get this to work.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I checked some other answers about this issue on stack overflow, but still couldn't manage to disable resizing on scroll function, depending on screen width.

I want this function to stop working when screen width is smaller than 900 px.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('.nav').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('.nav');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 600);
            $('.nav-collapse li a').css('height','40px');
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'80px'
            }, 600);
            $('.nav-collapse li a').css('height','80px');
        }  
        }
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than that. What function are you trying to disable? How is the code behaving presently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    var limiter = 900;

    $(function(){
        $('.nav').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ( $(window).width() > limiter ) { // here you go

            var $nav = $('.nav');
            if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                    $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                        height:'40px'
                    }, 600);
                    $('.nav-collapse li a').css('height','40px');
                }
            } else {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                    $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                        height:'80px'
                    }, 600);
                    $('.nav-collapse li a').css('height','80px');
                }  
            }
        }
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: No problem take care :)